# deserialize nested objects in json and assign to c# list

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists, json-deserialization

I have a json which I am reading and trying to convert to list of PackageCategory

```
[
    {
        "PackageCategory": [
            {
                "Size": "xxx",
                "Dimension": {
                    "Height": "000.0",
                    "Length": "1200.0",
                    "Breadth": "3300.0"
                },
                "Cost": "10.0m"
            },

            {

                "Size": "yyy",
                "Dimension": {
                    "Height": "1200.0",
                    "Length": "1400.0",
                    "Breadth": "5500.0"
                },
                "Cost": "790.5m"

            },
            {

                "Size": "zzz",
                "Dimension": {
                    "Height": "2550.0",
                    "Length": "4030.0",
                    "Breadth": "1600.0"
                },
                "Cost": "8.5m"

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to deserialize it to C# list object List

```
public class PackageCategory
    {
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public PackageSize Dimension { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
public class PackageSize
    {
        public double Height { get; }
        public double Length { get; }
        public double Breadth { get; }
}
```

I am using below code but getting null values to the list object listObjects

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"\ListOfPackageCategory.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var listObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<packageCategory>>(json)
}
```

Also tried with

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var listObjects = ser.Deserialize<List<PackageCategory>>(json);
```

This also didnt work
Please help to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Root` object to deserialize:
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>`:

```cs
class Root
{
    public List<PackageCategory> PackageCategory;
}
```